# R error in FRSB package

Tags: r, fuzzy-logic

I'm testing FRSB, for classification task.
Everything is ok with FRBCS.W, FRBCS.CHI and FH.GBML , but it's an error with GFS.GCCL and SLAVE :
"object 'temp.rule.degree' not found"

I've tested different control lists but got always the same error message...

like this for SLAVE :

> control <- list(num.labels = 5, persen_cross = 0.9, max.iter = 100,
>               max.gen = 100, persen_mutant = 0.3, k.low = 0,
>               k.upper= 1, epsilon = 0.7)

Could you help ?

Thanx,

Blo